# Webpack required throwing Target container is not a DOM element when using Create-React-App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to recreate the boilerplate and setup a fresh dev ReactJS environment which following mimic [this repo](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter), by using `Create-React-App`.

I've made sure that I can see the default landing page on `http://localhost:3000/` before proceed making the changes.

Below are the steps I've gone thru:

1. Delete all files inside `src` folder
2. `npm install react-redux redux`
3. Add `index.js` at `src` folder
4. Add `components`, `reducers` directory at `src` folder
5. Add `app.js` at `src/components/` folder
6. Add `index.js` at `src/reducers/` folder

Below are the content of the files

> src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

> src/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  state: (state = {}) => state
});

export default rootReducer;
```

> src/components/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>React simple starter</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm hitting error below

[image]

**UPDATES**

Based on the feedbacks, i'm including my `index.html` as below

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAq06l5RUVfib62IYRQacLc-KAy0XIWAVs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your html file? it seems there is no document.querySelector('.container') element in you html-file. So react can't mount your application

Comment: You need to verify if you index.html file has an element with class name "container". It sounds like it does not exist.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson: Please have a look at my `index.html`

Answer (score 2):

If you use react-create-app, it generates an HTML-file, where no `document.querySelector('.container')`. Instead of it, this html file has `<div id="root"></div>`, so you can try to change from `document.querySelector('.container')` to `document.querySelector('#root')`.
If it doesn't help, show please your HTML-file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, please help have a look at my `index.html`.

Comment: I created a project on GitHub https://github.com/xnimorz/stackoverflow-example/tree/51517890 . You can clone it, checkout to the 51517890 branch and check if this project will work correctly. Here I use react-create-app and your code. I think the main problem was that your html file wasn't resolved. 
Also, there is a result of `yarn built` command https://xnimorz.github.io/stackoverflow-example/

Comment: I've tested multiple rounds, steps by steps, still couldnt make it and hitting same problem, I think the problem is with installing react-redux and redux

Comment: Right after `CRA` command, I ran `npm install --save react-redux redux`, this command removed 1305 packages and the app crashed, and what I had to do is running `yarn install` to install the missing packages